# Issue with Laravel When Calling Laravel API from Another Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with two Laravel projects, **Project One** and **Project Two**, running on my localhost. **Project One** makes API calls to **Project Two**. Both projects use separate MySQL databases, with **Project Two** configured to use a non-default connection named *mysql_oth* in *config/database.php*. However, when **Project One** makes an API call to **Project Two, Project Two** attempts to use the default (**Project one's**) mysql database connection instead of mysql_oth. This issue does not occur when making requests to **Project Two** directly via **Postman**; the correct *mysql_oth* connection is used in that case.

Here's what I've verified so far:

1. The **mysql_oth** connection is correctly configured in **Project Two's
   config/database.php.**
2. Direct calls to **Project Two's API** endpoint from
   **Postman** correctly utilize the **mysql_oth** connection.
3. The issue only arises when **Project One** makes an API call to **Project Two**; somehow, it causes **Project Two** to revert to the default (**Project one's**) mysql connection. I
4. I have cleared Laravel's configuration, route, and cache using artisan
   commands in both projects.

Code of Project One :

```
$request->authenticate();

    

$request->session()->regenerate();
    
    $response = Http::post('http://localhost:82/laravel/project_2/api/appLogin', [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ])->throw();
    

    if ($response->successful()) {
        $token = $response->json('token');
        
        $request->session()->put('apptoken', $token); // Save token in session
        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    } else {
        
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        
        return redirect(url('login'))->withErrors(['email' => 'The provided credentials are incorrect -- .']);
    }
```

Project two Code :

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        Log::info('API call sent', [
            'method' => request()->method(),
            'url' => request()->url(),
            'data' => request()->all(),
        ]);
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication successful
            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
            return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
        } else {
            // Authentication failed
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
        }
    }
```

ENV settings:

Project one

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project_one,
```

Project Two

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql_oth
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project_two
```

Questions:

1. Why does **Project Two** switch to the **default (Project one's)** database connection when called from **Project One** , and how can I prevent this?
2. Is there a Laravel-specific configuration or runtime aspect that I might be overlooking, which could cause this behavior?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: aside from *config/database.php*, did you also check the .env of project 2 ?

Comment: This might be a configuration issue in project 2 in .env file where DB_HOST, etc is the same with project 1. Also try to cache clear both project (you might have make them the same at one point, cached then update project 2 **might have**)

Comment: yes, I did twice check that. It's perfect @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: Project one DB_CONNECTION=mysql DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=project_one,
Project Two DB_CONNECTION=mysql_oth DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306 DB_DATABASE=project_two @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: I have a project that works in two app  parallel, saving data in one will be sending to another directly by the app. It's not sigle page application. @krisgjika

Comment: This is clearly a misconfiguration somewhere. If postman does work as expected, but project one -> project two call does not using exactly the same endpoint and data, then, it is for sure a configuration thing... what about your infra? do you have multiple servers serving project one and two? I am more incline to think you have some old configuration somewhere, like a cache, or in-memory (running on the PHP-FPM workers) or something like that... share how your infra is, and also share exactly how the postman call is done, you are not sharing something with us

Comment: I'm working on localhost. I do not have setup multiservers. I have cleared all cached, configurations by artisan commands. 

Postman return "{
    "token": "14|FbNycesYBEtKsFWyeAUnON95vfi5HQQkfIxiIxul"
}" @matiaslauriti

Comment: Oh, wait, if it is local environment in your machine, how are you running both projects? Are you using `php artisan serve` or similar? are you using docker?

Comment: localhost->htdocs->projects. @matiaslauriti

Comment: @chigs Have you confirmed that Project One API is hitting the Project Two controller method?  I suggest you to run both projects using php artisan serve which give you different ports, It would be easy for debugging

Comment: Yes, I did try that also. It's not working. Another weird thing is that the same code is working if I put it on my server with diffrent sub domains. @SaravanaSai

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Queued Jobs,
ensure that these Jobs are NOT co-mingling at the Queue-level.

If both sites are running on the same server,
using the same default configs,
you may be inadvertently queueing them to the same queue (Redis: default)
Allowing PHP Worker Processes FROM BOTH APPLICATIONS to process these requests.
This can be difficult to diagnose because:

- it occurs intermittently
- The Job code is correct (for each codebase)
- The Errors don't seem to make sense
  The defining behavior is that the data and code for the multiple applications keeps getting mismatched:  pieces of data are executed by the wrong code

It gets a little tricky how to keep them separate (depending on how you've configured your queues.

If you are using Horizon, it can further confuse the issue because it is automating everything (and inadvertently disguising the root of the problem.

Differentiate the multiple Applications by:

- hosting on different servers (overkill IMO)
- isolate the applications (if using Forge, this is simple)
- isolate the job queues (any one of these should get you cleaned up)

  - Application #1: use 'database'
  - Application #2: use 'beanstalk', 'sqs',...
  - if using Redis: REDIS_DB={0,1,2,3,4,5..15)

    - or REDIS_PREFIX, or HORIZON_PREFIX,...
      After deploying code or changes to the .env files for any of your Applications:
- Avoid old configs from lingering around:  php artisan config:clear (then config:cache)
- Clear out old Queued Jobs, Failed Jobs, and Batches that may be waiting to run, but are already misconfigured

  - php artisan queue: clear  (then  queue: flush, prune-batches, prune-failed
  - restart the queue workers:  php artisan queue: restart

- If you're using Horizon to manage your Queues and Workers, use the horizon commands

Hope these insights help.
I've learned by kicking my shins on as many obstacles as I could find (or couldn't find)